# SQL Select multiple rows using where in one table

Tags: sql

I have a table named "Student".

```
 Student
    id | name | age
    1  | john | 10
    2  | jack | 10
    3  | jerry| 10
```

I wanna select 1 and 2 rows. I wrote that `Select * from Student where name=john and name=jack`
But return "Empty Set". 
How do i do it. Help me.

Comment: Thanks for all. But I want to select 2 rows with which name equal 'john' and 'jack'.

Comment: Everyone's answer does that.  Have you tried it?  I've tried to explain it in my answer, if you comment on what you don't understand I can try to explain further.  But I strongly recommend you try it and see.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
select *
from student
where name in ('john', 'jack')
```

Or

```
select *
from student
where name = 'john'
or name = 'jack'
```

Comment: Thank you. I realize that. But I wanna select 1 and 2 rows. is it impossible?

Comment: @Dems Haha I'm enjoying our virtual collisions this evening.

Comment: @Munkhjin That would select your first and second rows.  Is this not what you're looking for?  You could always do `select top 2 * from student order by id`.  But I would have thought my original answer would have been your solution as well.

Comment: @Munkhjin - That *does* select those two rows.  Try it and see.  I've tried to explain it a little in my answer, but testing it for yourself is often a better way to convince yourself :)

Comment: oh man.. such a simple solution and I have been trying for an hour!!! :* .. IN(....) works great for me

Answer (score 4):

You need an `OR` rather than an `AND`.

Whatever conditions your write, it checks them all against each record.  As no single record has both `name = 'john'` AND `name = 'jack'` they all fail.

If, instead, you use `OR`...
- The 1st record yields `TRUE OR FALSE` which is TRUE.
- The 2nd record yields `FALSE OR TRUE` which is TRUE.
- The 3rd record yields `FALSE OR FALSE` which is FALSE.

```
Select * from Student where name='john' OR name='jack'
```

Or, using a differnt way of saying it all...

```
SELECT * FROM Student WHERE name IN ('john', 'jack')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes to surround your values, plus use and instead of or:

```
where name='john' or name = 'jack'
```

Answer (score -1):

try this one.

```
  declare @names varchar(100)
  set @names='john,jack'
  Select * from Student 
 where charIndex(',' + rtrim(cast(name as nvarchar(max))) + ',',',' +isnull(@names,name) +',') >0
```